# "Mortals" vs "Human Beings"

Tags: meaning, nouns

There is a book titled *Running for Mortals*. I didn't recognize word *mortal*. Then I looked up it and get the meaning as below.

> **mortal** N - A human being

I wonder, is *mortal* widely used as *human being* or it is used only for special areas like sports, medical, etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word *mortal* is used to describe people in contrast to *immortals*, beings that cannot die, such as gods or similar entities in works of fiction or myth. You wouldn’t use the word *mortal* to refer to humans in any context except one where humans were being either implicitly or explicitly compared to gods.

The book title *Running for Mortals* is kind of a joke, implying that unlike other books containing advice and instruction for runners that are only applicable to those with godlike ability, stamina, and discipline, this book can be used by *mere mortals*.

Comment: @All, Thank you. Actually I already ordered two books (another one is *Marathoning for Mortals*)yesterday via online store. The international package will delivered to me about 20 days later. Really want to read it right now.

Comment: This way of using the word *mortals* is probably a result of the influences of ancient Greek culture, in which human beings were often referred to as mortals, with implied contrast to gods. Until a couple of generations ago, some exposure to ancient Greek culture was a standard feature of general education, so this way of referring to humans was familiar to many educated people.

Answer (score 6):

The word "mortal" means "subject to death," meaning if one can be killed, one is mortal. It does not apply specifically to any one topic.

The title *Running for Mortals* is a nod to the notion that hardcore distance runners are "superhuman."

Comment: @Nano: Sometimes, you'd encounter things like "could you explain it in a way mere mortals like me would understand?" ; the speaker is essentially imploring the one being talked to to explain more clearly, hopefully using less jargon.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your suggestion and statement sample.